# Things not physically moving very hard to concentrate upon - suggestions?

Tags: learning, concentration, adhd

Hello dear cogsci users,

I am a (fledgling) programmer by profession, **one who also squarely fits the description of an ADHD person**.

The symptoms have been making it tremendously hard for me to advance my career. However, I refuse to be put on meds - I'm a firm believer in fixing neurobiological defects with the proper diet and exercise (and have already noticed that curbing my carbohydrate intake alleviates much of the problem).

Somewhat surprisingly, I discovered that **if either me or the things I'm studying were in motion, learning most anything became a breeze**.

Things I have come up with to combat my concentration issues:

1) To pass my math exams, I would hop on the bus and do my algebra/calculus there - the changing scenery made me both concentrate better on the task at hand, and provided natural 'hooks' to remember things such as formulas (as they were automatically paired up with the places I was passing through). I had used to fail classes because of math in secondary school, but got an A on the exam for which I was 'studying in motion'.

2) When reading eBooks or some such, setting the screen to slowly scroll downwards greatly improves my concentration (by about a half).

3) Keeping widgets such as the Windows desktop clock within my field of vision also helps.

4) I have been thinking about using a rhytmically shifting, dynamic background for the applications I use to learn (browser, eBook reader). The Ubuntu Linux 'it is raining' desktop effect also really helps me concentrate.

**However, I need a powerful, overarching technique that I could use during studying, one that would also be easy to access anywhere.**

Would you have any interesting suggestions? In exchange, I welcome you to use any and all of my observations for research.

BTW: I do not believe I am primarly kinesthetic (more like auditory first [knack for picking up foreign languages], kinesthetic second, visual third).

Comment: I'm also only able to concentrate reading with something moving, something animated, it feels like I am 500% more awake, would like to see some answers :)

Comment: @Enoque - look into SPD (Sensory Processing Disorder). It has similar symptoms to ADD/ADHD, but is not temporarily alleviated after taking stimulants. Exactly my case.

In kids, it is treated with sensory integration therapy (yay, no drugs!) - something we might try as well.

Comment: I made a script that [animates all letters on a webpage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hMGpq.png). Would that help? :D

Comment: Requiring certain movements from self or environment may be an example of [stimming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimming), which is often seen in [autism spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum), among other conditions.